# c++ program not working in code block IDE

Tags: c++, random

i have a simple C++ program to generate uniform distributed random numbers, the program is working properly in visual studio. but when i run it in the code block IDE i get repeated random number, how can i fix that pleas?

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <ctime>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
double Rand()
{
random_device seeder;
    const auto seed = seeder.entropy() ? seeder() : time(nullptr);
    mt19937 eng(static_cast<mt19937::result_type>(seed));
    uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 1);
    auto gen = bind(dist, eng);
    return gen();
}
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    cout<<Rand()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not the most efficient way to generate random numbers. But what output do you get? Do you get the same number repeated? Or a pattern of repeated numbers? Or do you get the same numbers every time you run the program?

Comment: thank you for replying, i want a function to return a random number between 0 and 1. i get the same number repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the `Rand()` function like this:

```
double Rand()
{
    static random_device seeder;
    static mt19937 eng(seeder());
    uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 1);
    return dist(eng);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ayZTRW).

Comment: so why the same code gives a set of different random numbers in visual studio?

Comment: Hmm, not sure, maybe it's been fixed now. Added a working solution anyway.

Comment: *"random_device is non-deterministic"* [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) says it doesn't have to be. *"same results every time entropy() is called"* It's not a problem though. `random_device` does work in libc++, even if the return value of `entropy()` doesn't change.

Comment: unfortunately, i get the same numbers every time i run the program.

Comment: Oh, yes I think my original answer didn't necessari;ly solve your problem. The snippet should be fine though.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code.

First, it decides if it should use `std::random_device` based on the value of `.entropy()`.

I'm not sure if it correctly detects the broken `random_device` of pre-GCC-9.2 MinGW (which returns the same sequence of numbers every time you run the program), and I don't have an old MinGW on my hands to check that. But in any case, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy), it will incorrectly decide to avoid `random_device` on libc++, where `.entropy()` always returns `0`.

My suggestion would be to use `std::random_device` unconditionally. If you have an old MinGW where it's broken, update the compiler.

The second problem is that it recreates `mt19937 eng` each time the function is called, which doesn't make much sense. It should probably be `static`. If the code uses time-based seeding (`.entropy()` happens to return 0), then it might give you the same number because the function is called several times without delay; otherwise it's just inefficient.

Here's the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

double Rand()
{
    static std::mt19937 eng(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 1);
    return dist(eng);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << Rand() << std::endl;
}
```

I've also removed the `std::bind` call, which was completely unnecessary, and the `std::srand` call, which didn't do anything because you don't use `std::rand`.

If this program gives you the same numbers every time you run it, it probably means that you have an old MinGW where `random_device` is broken. Then update the compiler. (MSYS2 is a good way to get a bleeding-edge GCC on Windows.)